# How do I start banshee in the mode where I can get a crash log

Tags: banshee

How do I start banshee in the mode where I can get a log? Its crashing while syncing with my Cowon iAudio 9.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type `banshee --debug`.

If you need any further help with the output add it the your question by pressing the `edit` button under it and change the title to reflect your problem.

You can also save the output text by running `banshee --debug > ~/banshee_debug`, it will save the output to a file called `banshee_debug` in your `home` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain a debug log by running the following or if/as recommended in your bug report otherwise:

Open a terminal and type:

**Linux:**

```
cd ~; banshee --debug 2>&1 | tee banshee-debug-log.txt
```

Reproduce your problem and exit banshee and attach the resulting banshee-debug-log.txt to your bug report

(the banshee-debug-log.txt will be in the base of your home directory)

Here's the source [link](http://live.gnome.org/Banshee/CommonQuestions/Logs).

Comment: Why is the MacOS X command even there?

Comment: I left that originally since there's a wide audience that utilizes askubuntu, and thought that it might get others to feel welcome. I didn't think it would be necessary to remove the reference to MacOS X.